# How to append() two dimensional array/list in python 3 with for-in loop?

Tags: python, arrays

For a one-dimensional array/list, we would simply do this in a loop, in case it is being input:

```
a = input()
ch.append(a)
```

But how to append a two dimensional array which has two for-in loops, one nested inside other?

Comment: `which has two for-in loops` what does it mean? Please provide some code and expected result.

Comment: `a = input()` so `input` is a function? Your code makes no sense.

Comment: @MbKam Can you please provide sample input and expected output so it will be clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear to me, however, I would recommend you to look into the different numpy function:

`np.concatenate`
`np.hstack` `np.vstack` `np.c_`

etc.